# Finding all combinations of length 3 from a set of numbers such that sum(combination) is 0

Tags: python, permutation, list-comprehension

Suppose S is a set of integers, e.g `{-4,-2,1,2,5,0}`. I want to write a comprehensions in order to get a a list of all three-element tuples `(i,j,k)` such that `i,j,k` are elements of S and `i+j+k == 0`.

Comment: We won't do your homework. You need to show some effort on your own first.

Comment: You tried something yourself?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, it looks like you've recieved a school assignment or want us to do all the work for you. Al tho we tend to help out in any way we can we would like you to show some form of effort yourself.. What have you tried thus far? Did you bump into any errors that we can help with? Show us what you've tried and we can bump you into the right direction, but coding everything for you or finding libraries for you is not what stackoverflow is ment for.

Comment: must i,j,k be different elements of S?

Comment: am not doing any homework, just got stuck in some linear algebra computations in python. So your help will be needed without any libraries used. @timgeb i,j,k can be any of the example set.

Comment: If you want a good way to do it, then why don't you want to use the standard library?

Comment: @Petsome, you have used combination in your question which is different from a permutation, it might help if you clarified whether you want combinations or permutations as they are two very different things.

Comment: Addition to the question, the answer is just one single line comprehension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Original post:

As far as I am understanding your question and the answer to my comment, any value in `i,j,k` may be any value from your set `S`.

```
>>> [(i,j,k) for i in S for j in S for k in S if i+j+k == 0]
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 2, -2), (0, -2, 2), (1, 1, -2), (1, -2, 1), (2, 0, -2), (2, 2, -4), (2, -4, 2), (2, -2, 0), (-4, 2, 2), (-2, 0, 2), (-2, 1, 1), (-2, 2, 0)]
```

---

**EDIT**

Since the question was clarified, i.e. the same value cannot be chose twice, this answer needs an update.

```
>>> from itertools import permutations, combinations
>>> S={-4,-2,1,2,5,0}
>>> [x for x in permutations(S,3) if sum(x) == 0]
[(0, 2, -2), (0, -2, 2), (2, 0, -2), (2, -2, 0), (-2, 0, 2), (-2, 2, 0)]
>>> [x for x in combinations(S,3) if sum(x) == 0]
[(0, 2, -2)]
```

Use either `permutations` or `combinations` (I still have not figured out which of these you want).

Comment: This, incorrectly I believe, allows the same number from `S` to be picked up to 3 times...as shown, for example, in the first group of numbers `(0, 0, 0)`. The `S` in the OP's question only has one `0` in it.

Comment: @martineau I asked the OP for clarification if the same number can be chosen multiple times, and as far as I understood his answer, this behavior is allowed.

Comment: @timgeb the same number can't be chosen multiple times. It must be chosen at most once, but the sum of the three tuples must be equals to 0.

Answer (score 1):

The [itertools docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) actually show you the equivalent python code for combinations

```
def combinations(iterable, r):
    # combinations('ABCD', 2) --> AB AC AD BC BD CD
    # combinations(range(4), 3) --> 012 013 023 123
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = range(r)
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
    while True:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            if indices[i] != i + n - r:
                break
        else:
            return
        indices[i] += 1
        for j in range(i+1, r):
            indices[j] = indices[j-1] + 1
        yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)

print [ x for x in combinations(s,3) if sum(x)==0]
[(0, 2, -2)]
```

Comment: I think any value in `i,j,k` may be any value from the set (check the comments on the question)

Comment: @timgeb combinations and permutations are two different things, the OP uses combination in the question so I have provided a combination solution.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the same number can not be used more than once to calculate the sum:

```
from itertools import combinations

S = {-4, -2, 1, 2, 5, 0}
zero_sums = [(i, j, k) for i, j, k in combinations(S, 3) if not sum((i, j, k))]
print(zero_sums)  # -> [(0, 2, -2)]
```

You can verify that this is correct by printing all the combinations and their sums:

```
for i, j, k in combinations(S, 3):
    print('({:2d}, {:2d}, {:2d}) = {:2d}'.format(i, j, k, sum((i, j, k))))
```

Output:

```
( 0,  1,  2) =  3
( 0,  1,  5) =  6
( 0,  1, -4) = -3
( 0,  1, -2) = -1
( 0,  2,  5) =  7
( 0,  2, -4) = -2
( 0,  2, -2) =  0
( 0,  5, -4) =  1
( 0,  5, -2) =  3
( 0, -4, -2) = -6
( 1,  2,  5) =  8
( 1,  2, -4) = -1
( 1,  2, -2) =  1
( 1,  5, -4) =  2
( 1,  5, -2) =  4
( 1, -4, -2) = -5
( 2,  5, -4) =  3
( 2,  5, -2) =  5
( 2, -4, -2) = -4
( 5, -4, -2) = -1
```